# How to add different Description for every Checkbox in Zend MultiCheckbox Class

Tags: zend-framework

How to add different Description for every Checkbox in Zend MultiCheckbox Class

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
  $this->addElement('MultiCheckbox', 'multicheck', array(
   'label'=>'Checkboxes',
   'multiOptions'=>array(1=>'Label 1', 2=>'Label 2')
  ));
```